# Joomla 2.5 custom component: create path on install

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

My custom component needs a certain path, say `/images/example/photos`.

How can I create it on installation, but only if it doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an install script. To get is set up, have a look at this:

[Adding an Install/Uninstall/Update script file](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file)

You can remove all the functions but keep the **install** function. Your final install function should look like this:

```
function install($parent) {

    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

    if(!JFolder::exists(JPATH_ROOT . '/media/images/example/photos')) {
         $path = JPATH_SITE . '/media/images';
         $folder = 'example/photos';
         JFolder::create( $path .'/'. $folder, 0755 );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps